# Plot frequency of dates in interval occurred in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with dates from year 1970 to year 2018, I want to plot frequency of occurrences from year 2016 to 2017.

```
In[95]: df['last_payout'].dtypes
Out[95]: dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

The data is stored in this format:

```
In[96]: df['last_payout'].head
​​
Out[96]: <bound method NDFrame.head of 0         1970-01-01
1         1970-01-01
2         1970-01-01
3         1970-01-01
4         1970-01-01
```

I plot this by year using `group by` and `count` :

```
 In[97]: df['last_payout'].groupby(df['last_payout'].dt.year).count().plot(kind="bar")
```

[image]

I want to get this plot between specific dates, I tried to put `df['last_payout'].dt.year > 2016`, but I got this:

[image]

How do I get the plot for specific date range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need filter by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-04-03', periods=10, freq='7M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'last_payout': rng})  
print (df)
  last_payout
0  2015-04-30
1  2015-11-30
2  2016-06-30
3  2017-01-31
4  2017-08-31
5  2018-03-31
6  2018-10-31
7  2019-05-31
8  2019-12-31
9  2020-07-31

(df.loc[df['last_payout'].dt.year.between(2016, 2017), 'last_payout']
       .groupby(df['last_payout'].dt.year)
       .count()
       .plot(kind="bar")
)
```

Alternative solution:

```
(df.loc[df['last_payout'].dt.year.between(2016, 2017), 'last_payout']
         .dt.year
         .value_counts()
         .sort_index()
         .plot(kind="bar")
)
```

[image: graph]

EDIT: For months with years convert datetimes to month period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
(df.loc[df['last_payout'].dt.year.between(2016, 2017), 'last_payout']
         .dt.to_period('M')
         .value_counts()
         .sort_index()
         .plot(kind="bar")
)
```

Comment: where relevant_df is the one from Ami Tavory's answer?

Comment: @user40 - oops, it was wrong.I hope now it working nice.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer, could you please also show how to extend the plot so it would have months on X-axis? Thanks

Comment: @user40 - Do you think year with month? like `2016-01` ? Or `month`s only without `year`s only?

Comment: Yes, year with month, like a timeline.

Comment: I am trying to sum all the values by amount. Would you please check the following question? Thanks!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712191/how-to-sum-all-amounts-by-date-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
df['last_payout'].dt.year > 2016
```

just returns a boolean series, so plotting this will indeed show a bar chart of the number of dates for which this is or not.

---

Try first creating a relevant df:

```
relevant_df = df[(df['last_payout'].dt.year > 2016) & (df['last_payout'].dt.year <= 2017)]
```

(use strict or not inequalities depending on what you want, of course.)

then performing the plot on it:

```
relevant_df['last_payout'].groupby(relevant_df['last_payout'].dt.year).count().plot(kind="bar")
```