# How to sum all amounts by date in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with fields `last_payout` and `amount`. I need to sum all `amount` for each month and plot the output.

```
df[['last_payout','amount']].dtypes

last_payout    datetime64[ns]
amount           float64
dtype: object
```

-

```
df[['last_payout','amount']].head

<bound method NDFrame.head of                last_payout  amount
0      2017-02-14 11:00:06          23401.0
1      2017-02-14 11:00:06          1444.0
2      2017-02-14 11:00:06          0.0
3      2017-02-14 11:00:06          0.0
4      2017-02-14 11:00:06          290083.0
```

I used the code from jezrael's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706852/plot-frequency-of-dates-in-interval-occurred-in-pandas-dataframe/49706980?) to plot the number of transactions per month.

```
(df.loc[df['last_payout'].dt.year.between(2016, 2017), 'last_payout']
         .dt.to_period('M')
         .value_counts()
         .sort_index()
         .plot(kind="bar")
)
```

Number of transactions per month:

[image: Number of transactions per month]

How do I sum all `amount` for each month and plot the output? How should I extend the code above for doing this?

I tried to implement `.sum` but didn't succeed.

Comment: Minor tip: use `df.head()`, not `df.head`. `head` is a *method* designed to be called using parentheses, which produces much nicer output :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**PeriodIndex** solution:

[`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `month` period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df['amount'].groupby(df['last_payout'].dt.to_period('M')).sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

---

**DatetimeIndex** solutions:

Use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `month`s (`M`) or starts of months (`MS`) with aggregate `sum`:

```
s = df.resample('M', on='last_payout')['amount'].sum()
#alternative
#s = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='last_payout'))['amount'].sum()
print (s)
last_payout
2017-02-28     23401.0
2017-03-31      1444.0
2017-04-30    290083.0
Freq: M, Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

Or:

```
s = df.resample('MS', on='last_payout')['amount'].sum()
#s = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='last_payout'))['amount'].sum()
print (s)
last_payout
2017-02-01     23401.0
2017-03-01      1444.0
2017-04-01    290083.0
Freq: MS, Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

Then is necessary format `x` labels:

```
ax = s.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xticklabels(s.index.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

[image: graph]

**Setup**:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""last_payout,amount
2017-02-14 11:00:06,23401.0
2017-03-14 11:00:06,1444.0
2017-03-14 11:00:06,0.0
2017-04-14 11:00:06,0.0
2017-04-14 11:00:06,290083.0"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[0])
print (df)
          last_payout    amount
0 2017-02-14 11:00:06   23401.0
1 2017-03-14 11:00:06    1444.0
2 2017-03-14 11:00:06       0.0
3 2017-04-14 11:00:06       0.0
4 2017-04-14 11:00:06  290083.0
```

Comment: @user40 - You are welcome. Please dont forget upvote/accept solution. Thanks.

Comment: This solution does not work any more in v 2.1, it throws an error: 'TypeError: datetime64 type does not support sum operations'  any suggestions?

Comment: @cJc - Do you try data from answer? Because `amount` are numbers, so cannot raise error `TypeError: datetime64 type does not support sum operations`

Answer (score 0):

You can group by month-start (`'MS'`) using `resample`:

```
df.set_index('last_payout').resample('MS').sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: I get this, when I try to implement the code: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer. You need `df.set_index('last_payout').resample('MS').sum().plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: Do I get it right, this line performs summing for all other fields in the df? Besides 'last_payout' and 'amount' I also have other fields in the df that I didn't mention. How do I specify that the sum should be taken for 'amount' field only? Thank you

Comment: I created another dataframe with last_payout and amount columns only, but still something is not right, this is what i got: http://joxi.net/52a1jkxh4OJZe2.jpg